# Python - create one list for many json files

Tags: python, json, list

I am looking up a folder in order to print all `json` files in one go:

```
path_to_json = 'playlists/'
json_files = [pos_json for pos_json in os.listdir(path_to_json) if pos_json.endswith('.json')]

for js in json_files:
  with open(os.path.join(path_to_json, js)) as json_file:
    playlists = json.load(json_file)
    print playlists
```

the code prints me this:

```
   {
    "user1": {
        "Make You Feel My Love": 1.0, 
        "I See Fire": 1.0, 
        "High And Dry": 1.0, 
        "Fake Plastic Trees": 1.0, 
        "One": 1.0, 
        "Goodbye My Lover": 1.0, 
        "No Surprises": 1.0
    }
}
{
    "user2": {
        "Codex": 1.0, 
        "No Surprises": 1.0, 
        "O": 1.0, 
        "Go It Alone": 1.0
    }
}
{
    "user3": {
        "Fake Plastic Trees": 1.0, 
        "High And Dry": 1.0, 
        "No Surprises": 1.0
    }
}
{
    "user4": {
        "No Distance Left To Run": 1.0, 
        "Running Up That Hill": 1.0, 
        "Fake Plastic Trees": 1.0, 
        "The Numbers": 1.0, 
        "No Surprises": 1.0
    }
}
{
    "user5": {
        "Wild Wood": 1.0, 
        "You Do Something To Me": 1.0, 
        "Reprise": 1.0
    }
}
```

how do I change the code so I can end up with a `list` containing all of the above `dictionaries`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply create a list and append each of the dictionary objects to the list at each iteration of the `for`:

```
lst = []
for js in json_files:
    with open(os.path.join(path_to_json, js)) as json_file:
        playlists = json.load(json_file)
        lst.append(playlists)
```